# Using array_sum() filtered from another array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$type=array("debit", "credit", "credit", "credit", "debit");

$amount=array(20,30,40,50,60);
```

how to `array_sum` all `debit` values or all `credit` values?

expected result: 
debit= 20+60 = 80
credit=30+40+50 =120

I've tried to filter it then use array_sum but not working.

```
function filterDebit($finddebit){
    return ($finddebit == "debit");
}
$finaldebit = array_filter($type, 'filterDebit');
echo array_sum($finaldebit);
```

Comment: must it be `array_sum`? can it be a foreach?

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai No problem with foreach. What matters is the end result. :)

Comment: Are these 2 separate arrays?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter: Yes. They are separate array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quite get the sum that way because you aren't actually doing anything with the array of amounts, but you've already gotten pretty close.

You can use `array_intersect_key` to find the entries in `$amount` that match the keys in your filtered `$types` array.

```
echo array_sum(array_intersect_key($amount, $finaldebit));
```

---

If it's possible, I think it would be better to address this problem at some earlier point, so the two sets of associated values don't end up in separate arrays like this, *especially* if the two arrays came from a database, which would be able to handle this filtering/aggregation more efficiently, but since I don't know the source of the arrays, I don't have a suggestion for that.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can do like this without any complex logic: *(Explanation inline)*

```
$type = array('debit', 'credit', 'credit', 'credit', 'debit');

$amount = array(20, 30, 40, 50, 60);

$sum = array_fill_keys(array_unique($type), 0);  // initialize the empty associative array with possible keys from $type array

foreach ($type as $key => $t) {
    $sum[$t] += $amount[$key]; // Sum up the values based on keys
}

print_r($sum);
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [debit] => 80
    [credit] => 120
)
```

---

**Note:** Make sure your both arrays hold right values. Since both are different there might be some discrepancies if values don't match!

Answer (score 1):

You may go with [@Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531060/2119863)'s answer, or do it by hand with a for loop

```
function sumType($type, $amount, $key){
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($type); $i++){
        if ($type[$i] == $key){
            $sum += $amount[$i];
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

$type=array("debit", "credit", "credit", "credit", "debit");
$amount=array(20,30,40,50,60);

echo sumType($type, $amount, 'debit'); // 80
echo sumType($type, $amount, 'credit'); // 120
```

Comment: @Thamilan's answer is also a great choice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531216/2119863

Answer (score 1):

@Don't Panic is more concrete, but you can do something like this as well.

```
<?php

$type=array("debit", "credit", "credit", "credit", "debit");

$amount=array(20,30,40,50,60);

function filter_price($types, $amount, $type){
    if($type == 'debit'){
        $key = 'debit';
    }else{
        $key = 'credit';
    }
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($types as $index->$type){
        if($type == $key){
            $sum += $amount[$index];
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
echo filter_price($type, $amount, 'debit');
echo filter_price($type, $amount, 'credit');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibly convoluted way of doing it - not only for debit, but for any unique value in `$type`:

```
foreach(array_unique($type) as $flag) {
   $i = -1;
   ${'sum_'.$flag} = array_reduce($amount, function($carry, $item) use($type, &$i, $flag) {
       $i++;
       return $carry += $type[$i] == $flag ? $item : 0;
   }, 0);
}
echo $sum_debit; //80
echo $sum_credit; //120
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$types=array("debit", "credit", "credit", "credit", "debit");

$amount=array(20,30,40,50,60);

function getSum ($type, $typeArr, $amountArr) {
  $sum = 0;
  $r = array_keys($typeArr, $type);
  foreach ($r as $idx) {
    $sum = $sum + (int)$amountArr[$idx];
  }
  return $sum;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop over one of the arrays and access the corresponding element in the other array using the current iteration's index.  To prevent a Warning while trying to add a value to a result group that hasn't been declared yet, use the null coalescing operator to default the value to 0 before adding the new value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ugvqM))

```
$types = ["debit", "credit", "credit", "credit", "debit"];
$amounts = [20,30,40,50,60];

$result = [];
foreach ($types as $i => $type) {
    $result[$type] = ($result[$type] ?? 0) + $amounts[$i];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'debit' => 80,
  'credit' => 120,
)
```